# create new branches using files from a single commit [not merged to master yet]

Tags: git, git-branch, gerrit, git-commit

Team,
I committed 9files in a single commit. I want to move the 6files in two different commits[branches]. how can we achieve this?

ex: Branch1 - 9files
I want to do this 
Branch1 - 3 files;
Branch2 - 3 files;
Branch3 - 3 files.

Please assist. I searched online but its confusing and I don't want to mess up. Note that my commit Branch1 with 9files Is not yet merged to master. its pushed only.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple, go back to the previous commit and add your files again.

```
git reset HEAD~1                      # soft reset, leaves working files intact
git add file1 file2 file3             # add your first 3 files 
git commit -m"change1"                # commit change
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch1 # push for review

# Repeat for next 3 files
git reset HEAD~1
git add file3 file4 file5
git commit -m"change2"
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch2

git reset HEAD~1
git add file6 file7 file9
git commit -m"change3"
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/branch3
```

Comment: guys it was so urgent that i just followed what below suggestion was and had to just manually copy files to non git dir..and then created new branch for every 3 files ...  but to me above is the solution i was looking for. i did not try it yet.. will try and update. thanks

Comment: But aren't you still left with original commit on original branch with 9 files?

Comment: That's Gerrit for you. Changes are not part of the repo until you approve them. You can easily amend your original change by not adding the files.